# How to refresh tab data when I m making any changes to another tab on same browser

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I opened my website on two tab of browser.
If I removed one item from cart from one tab.
And go to the other tab .
I saw item still is in the cart.
-When i refresh the page it is working properly.
-Is there any way so that My two tab are in sync without refreshing the tabs.

Comment: try calling a function on tabs...which will refresh your list data

Comment: I did that but is reducing my application performance.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way so that My two tab are in sync without refreshing the tabs

Yes by using the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API), which allows communication between tabs.

From the posted link:

> The Broadcast Channel API allows simple communication between browsing contexts (that is windows, tabs, frames, or iframes) with the same origin (usually pages from the same site).